# Where can I see what the screen dimensions are of an Android mobile phone

Tags: settings, screen

I have a Samsung Galaxy S mobile phone, I can't seem to find the dimensions of the screen (apart from looking it up on the internet of course).

But in general: can you somewhere see the correct screen dimensions of a mobile device's screen ?

Comment: I don't see it under settings. Check the manual? Dimensions of several screens were posted [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/what-size-should-images-be-for-android-wallpaper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way, which is strange. Maybe because it can't be changed they don't think we need to know?

You can install an app called "Screen Resolution" which will display your phones resolution if you really want to see it on your phone.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Android_devices) with most devices specs to help find the resolution. [Source matt :)](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/137/matt)
in a response on [what-size-should-images-be-for-android-wallpaper](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/what-size-should-images-be-for-android-wallpaper)?

Answer (score 1):

[GSMArena.com](http://www.gsmarena.com/), just to point one site of this type, list almost all mobile phones known, with their technical specs.

For you example Galaxy S, here it is the [dedicated page](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9000_galaxy_s-3115.php)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Screen&System](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=Screen%26System) provides screen resolution (pixels), pixel density (dpi), screen metrics, height, width, and diagonal in centimeters and inches.