# Can anyone identify the widgets or software used in this?

Tags: app-widgets

I see this image and i would like to configure my Android phone to look like this too :)
But I have trouble finding the software or widgets used.

Can someone help me to find/identify them?

http://www.flickr.com/photos/39965241@N03/3707753843/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mru is right about the [Android and Me News Widget](http://www.appbrain.com/app/android-and-me-news-widget/com.androidandme.widgets.rss).  Based on the dock at the bottom I'd also say mru's right about that being the Sense UI as well, which means the clock and weather widget is stock, but you can replicate it with these:

- [Weather Forecast & Clock Widget](http://www.appbrain.com/app/weather-forecast-clock-widget/org.fagod.wfc_widget)
- [Beautiful Widgets](http://www.appbrain.com/app/beautiful-widgets/com.levelup.beautifulwidgets)
- I have the [Fancy Widget](http://www.androidcentral.com/fancy-widget-looks-wee-bit-familiar) but it's no longer available because HTC thought it looked too much like their widget (you could probably find the apk out there somewhere)

The battery widget is called... [Battery Widget](http://www.appbrain.com/app/battery-widget/com.geekyouup.android.widgets.battery).  Also, you may be able to get those sense icons by using the [Sense UI Icons](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sense-ui-icons/com.nd.android.pandatheme.p_senseicons) app for [PandaHome](http://www.appbrain.com/app/pandahome/com.nd.android.pandahome).

The [wallpaper is his own](http://www.flickr.com/photos/39965241@N03/3717845933/sizes/z/in/set-72157621408865186/) formated for a G1/Hero (640x480).  More on [sizing wallpapers for specific Android phones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/what-size-should-images-be-for-android-wallpaper/2034#2034).

Comment: Thanx Matt :) A lot :D

Comment: I used to use Battery Widget until I got Cyanogen Mod.  Now I show the battery % inside of the battery icon in the notification bar.

Answer (score 1):

The widget in the middle is the "android and me rss widget".

What you see is basically the **sense UI**. 
You may try the accuweather widget for the weather. But it will possibly not look that shiny.