# How can I get the Android to use wallpapers sized to my screen resolution?

Tags: wallpaper, screen-resolution

When I only have one "desktop" on my Android phone and I select one of my photos for the wallpaper, it asks me to crop the image.  The cropping tool only allows an aspect ratio that has nothing to do with the real aspect ration of my phones screen resolution. Why?

I have a Samsung GT i5800 running Android 2.1update1.

Comment: related: [What size should images be for Android wallpaper?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/what-size-should-images-be-for-android-wallpaper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure this was present in Eclair (but it's possible I'm mis-remembering and this was a new feature in Froyo)  but when you select a picture in the gallery, at the cropping stage it should give you a choice of screen resolution/aspect ratios to use. One of them should be the resolution of your screen, the other one is for the side-ways scrolling multi-screen wallpaper.

I've ringed round the two selection options in the screenshot below, tap the wide option on the left for the multi-screen wallpaper and the one on the right to crop to a single screen. You should then be able to drag the crop box out to be the full picture (if you've got the aspect ratio right on your image).

[image]

Edit: This appears to be a Samsung TouchWiz feature, rather than a stock Android feature, it should still be present on OP's Samsung GT i5800.

Comment: That's interesting. I've never seen that before, and I don't seem to have them on my phone (CM7). Did you take that screenshot on your device or did you find it online somewhere?

Comment: @elder That's a screenshot from my phone, stock Samsung Gingerbread on an Galaxy S, but it's been in there the last few versions. I did think this was part of core Android as I only noticed it after reading about it on another site, but after a browse through Youtube wallpaper related videos it seems this may be a TouchWiz thing? Luckily the OP's on a Samsung device so should still have this.

Comment: If it is then I think I might actually have a reason to be a little jealous of TouchWiz. That's a convenient feature.

Comment: it's not in the GTi5800 :( - a version update hopefully will solve the problem later...

Comment: @Lance sorry to hear that, hope they update you from 2.1 at some point.

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, the aspect ratio is always for a 5 desktop scroll. If you have enabled only one desktop, the you'll see just the middle part of the wallpaper.

Comment: This is correct.  One way to force a picture in portrait orientation to display without cropping is to add black bars to the sides of the photo, turning it into a landscape image with the content you want in the middle.