# How to size wallpapers to not be cropped on Motorola Xoom WiFi

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, motorola-xoom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the default resolution of a wallpaper that fits the homescreen exactly in an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/what-is-the-default-resolution-of-a-wallpaper-that-fits-the-homescreen-exactly-i)

Hi I'm running EOS nigtlie #102 (although this is a problem no matter what rom) but how do I size images so that they arent cropped. I see alot about 5 screens and what not but I dont have the 5 screen feature never have since ICS. So what resolution should my images be so that they arnt zoomed when i apply them as a background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the wallpaper slideshow app on google play works great for making and image fit like a glove. For those who have the same problem check out the app its free and easy to use.

Comment: Please also add a Play Store link to the app