# Size a Wallpaper for Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0

Tags: wallpaper, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the default resolution of a wallpaper that fits the homescreen exactly in an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/what-is-the-default-resolution-of-a-wallpaper-that-fits-the-homescreen-exactly-i)

I want to be able to design my own Wallpaper for my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0. I have read on various websites what the resolution is via pixels, when I try to design for these resolutions i have to "crop" my picture and once I "crop" it, it looks blurry as if it set the quality lower as well.

Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0":
http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxytab2/7.0/index.html?type=find

Resolutions:

- 1024px x 600px
- 640px x 480px

So, I guess my main question is. What is the correct resolution for this device? Why is it cropping all my images, even if they are set at 640px x 480px?

Comment: This is **not** an exact duplicate, as **Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (7.0)** does not behave as described in either @KenB's answer or the article referenced ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen size is 600 x 1024 pixels in portrait mode.  That's not the same as the wallpaper size, since the wallpaper is bigger than a single screen (try scrolling your homescreens left and right to see this).

Usually you need to double the width, and from what I can see online this seems to be the case for the Tab as well.  So use 1200 x 1024.

Comment: Great, I found the duplicate after I answered ... :P

Comment: Thank you for answering. Apologies by it being a duplicate.