# Why doesn't my wallpaper scroll?

Tags: wallpaper

At first, my question was why I had to crop my wallpaper wider than it seemed to be, but I saw that that question was already asked and answered here: [Setting wallpaper - wrong orientation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39124/setting-wallpaper-wrong-orientation)

So now my question is, if wallpaper is cropped wide so that it can scroll when you switch between screens, how come mine doesn't move? I am using a picture I downloaded from the internet on my phone, and as far as I can tell it doesn't move at all no matter what I do.

If it matters, my phone is a Motorola Atrix HD.

Comment: If you swipe to the left or right on your homescreen (to switch to the previous or next screen), the wallpaper should *slightly* shift as well. Depending on how many screens you have, it might be really minimal (10% or less), so you probably didn't notice. It could as well be that the launcher you are using does not support that -- though I don't know any launcher not supporting it.

Comment: I have two screens, so I'm pretty sure the problem isn't too many screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launcher application on some phones does not provide the ability for a scrolling wallpaper, the only way to fix this would be to download a separate launcher.

Here is a list of most of them -

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=launcher&c=apps

Answer (score 0):

http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/586033-galaxy-s3-cheated-some-us-leaving-out-scrolling-wallpapers-2.html#post4756930

Citation: "Scrolling wallpapers glitch when they have infinite scrolling. If you scroll past the end of the wall paper, it'll sharply shift to the other side of the image. I would imagine some find this to be unsightly. The developers at Samsung probably see this as a problem and probably thought infinite scrolling was a more important feature than wallpaper scrolling."

Answer (score 0):

On some [LG devices](https://www.lg.com/us/mobile-phones/VS985/Userguide/425.html), go to **Settings - Display - Home screen - Swipe effect**, then choose **Panorama**.